# Why are "Fact Checking" questions not welcome on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

### Case

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825821/what-is-the-performance-difference-between-gawk-and?noredirect=1) which is now closed aimed to become a reference to point to when there's comment stating "This is not adapted for this case, X would be quicker".

According to the high rep users and then mod who closed this question not moving it to another StackExchange site I assume there's no correct target in Stack Exchange.

### My point of view

My feeling is that it can be really helpful as it would (at end) sum knowledge from each topic and give a clear factual overview over them.

I really think this question could have ended with a proper table comparing solutions and giving clues on which could better suit a need balancing performance/knowledge of the tool.

I'm a sysadmin, quite comfortable with awk/sed/bash, a little less with perl,ruby or php, even less with Go and Java, and C/C++ is too far behind me.

When it comes to have something to do in a confined time of execution I try to search what would be the more efficient and the less hard for me, I may choose something which is not the best performance but I'm more comfortable with or choose to dig into a tool because it is proven to be really quicker.

### The question :

Why Q/A aimed at doing a Fact Checking not welcome on StackOverflow ?

Is there a recommended place for this ? Is it not a candidate for community wiki ? At end what could be a correct target to avoid out site links ?

---

For thoose interested in the subject you may have a look [here](http://tensibai.github.io/benchmark-awk-vs/) to the results.

If someone wish to duplicate it to another kind of test, the source is [here](https://github.com/Tensibai/benchmark-awk-vs) (It could probably be enhanced)

Comment: This is exactly the reason I tried to suggest a sister site on Area to Stack Overflow that might accommodate programming questions that might run perpendicular to the style and expectations for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "Fact Checking", it's a plain old speed comparison. There's a billion possible answers, and of course, the best tool _depends on the input data as well as the specific task_, so at best it's a comparison for one or a few use cases. It's nowhere near being a reference of execution time for arbitrary tasks, and I'd assume creating such a reference would be impossible. It's also by definition _too broad_, and it doesn't solve a specific problem. All in all, a very bad fit for SO.

Comment: @l4mpi The question describe a usual use case of awk, where there's often talks about it vs a C program or Perl. That would at least give a starting point on a regex match per line with field ordering, which is quite a  common task.

Comment: To quote [a comment from the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825821/what-is-the-performance-difference-between-gawk-and?noredirect=1#comment47782483_29825821), _"This is an awful way of testing regex engines. It represents only a very very tiny of practical uses. You say you want to compare languages, but this excercise will not produce any data from which meaninful answers can be drawn."_ The further comments also make very valid points as to why it's simply not a good quesiton. It would maybe make a good blog post, but not a factual reference fit for SO.

Comment: @l4mpi This is not a comparison of regex engines, this a comparison on parsing a 10M lines file for match with a regex and reordering fields, regex engine performance is just a part, not the whole point.

Comment: Which by itself makes it _too broad_. Also, one can see that it's a bad fit by the answers the question got so far - one way to do the same thing in PHP, one in Ruby, and everything else is "here's the timings on my machine". How is that useful? How should that be reliably voted upon? What kind of answer could even be accepted?

Comment: @l4mpi That's stated in the question itself, answers are there to be aggregated by someone to make a definitive one. I'm not asking to understand why it is no fit, I'm asking why this is restrained and what is the prefered way to give reference for this kind of question.

Comment: I should I've titled this question a little differently, it makes it unclear.

Comment: The preferred way is _not to ask such questions on SO, because they're a bad fit_. As I said, it could maybe make an interesting blog post. And that the question itself states a convoluted scheme for answering is in itself a sign that it's simply not on topic for SO. And look at the current answers (yours included) - they don't even care about OPs restriction but simply contain a mixture of alternative implementations and timings; instead of one implementation which is then timed by whoever aggregates the "definitive" answer. All in all it's just a mess and not a good knowledge resource.

Comment: @l4mpi How don't I care about op restrictions ? (I asked in comments if others languages are allowed, and OP has answered positively). And yes, for now there's no definitive answer and the question has been closed within a few hours with no chance to get to its desired goal.

Comment: Quoting OP, _'The way this will work is that over the next couple of days many people will contribute "answers" which are the programs to be tested and then one person will test all of them on one platform._ - TL;DR OP says the answers should contain an alternate implementation, _not_ timings. Yours contains _four_ timings, and everybody else also takes this as "please time this on your machine with [mgn]awk". That just makes the answers an unusable mess.

Comment: @l4mpi This gives a comparison on the same machine between original awk and the alternative. As in my point of view answers would have been edited at end once there's one with all timings from a single machine.

Comment: That's one of the problems - everybody answers the question according to _their point of view_, and as the question is very broad and unspecified, those differing points of view don't result in a good knowledge resource. Seriously, just take a look at the answers the question got. Read all of them again, then think about what OP actually wants to achieve, and how the current answers help to achieve that goal - or rather, how many more answers you would need to even come close, and how they would have to differ in quality from the existing answers for someone to reasonably sort through them.

Comment: @l4mpi There should be only one answer at end, it's in the question itself (and re said a couple of time here and in the question comments): "and then all of the results will be collected into a single answer.". I don't get the problem having a question lives for a while before getting to a "final" state (which could be updated after). Specially when there's people interested in the subject and willing to participate, how could it harm giving it a chance and see what it gives at end ?

Comment: And I've been repeatedly saying that it's completely unrealistic to ever _reach_ that final state. Again, just look at the current answers. Not to mention it wouldn't even be _final_ because then somebody answers with a new algorithm or tool, or version n+1 of a language implements feature x twice as fast as version n which makes the timings obsolete, etc, etc, etc - every time this happens, the person who created the "final" answer would have to do the timings again, or somebody else would have to do _all_ timings again, to ensure they're comparable. That's simply not what SO is for.

Comment: @l4mpi Ok, that answer the why even if I disagree it's unrealistic and that I'm pretty sure it can be managed to be kept up to date with a correct CI system, any clue on the other points ?

Comment: The people suggestion the question be closed and citing issues of scope being too broad are all completely and utterly missing the point of the question despite myself and others having tried in vain to explain/clarify/restate it in various ways. All these suggestions about limiting the number of languages included and/or specifying a specific platform to execute on are just proving that the posters do not understand the question as asked. At this point it is now too late for the question to be successfully answered so please chalk it up as a missed opportunity, forget it, and move on.

Comment: @EdMorton if the question (as stated) needs no improvement and is a good fit for Stack Overflow; then why would so many people say the same thing about it? If you want one question to rule them all; then remember: Some things are just too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @George I did not say the question needed no improvement. I said that **I** do not know how to reword/restructure it to improve it. This question is NOT too broad as it has a very limited, specific scope but for some reason **I** cannot figure out how to write it in such a way that that is clear and no-one telling me `it's too broad` has so far been able to suggest a way to clarify it without completely changing the intent and/or limits of the question. It's like they're reading what they expect to see in it rather than what it actually says.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## The problem of scope

> Why Q/A aimed at doing a Fact Checking not welcome on StackOverflow ?

Let's have a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (emphasis mine).

> ### What types of questions should I avoid asking?
>
> […]
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. **Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page**.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. **If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much**.

Now, let's have a look at the first sentence of the question, together with the title:

> ### What is the performance difference between gawk and …?
>
> The question often comes up about whether to use gawk or mawk or C or some other language due to performance so let's create a canonical question/answer for a trivial and typical awk program.

Even without looking at the rest of the question, this doesn't seem like a question that is reasonably scoped. Also, it's very open-ended: new programming languages get created every other day, and some of them survive more than the first year. Where does one stop? At *what point* can one actually accept a *definite answer*?

### Trimming down the number of languages

But let's say that there are finite languages that one is interested into, e.g. G, G++, Chilli, Lama, Snake and Mocha (not sure whether those are real languages). Now the question has a much smaller scope. Only 7 total benchmarks. Or so one might think. There are still *several unknown parameters*. What language versions are going to be compared? Who decides what algorithm actually passes the test? Is a fast algorithm that has UB better than a safe one that doesn't expose UB?

At this point we're slowly transitioning from a objective measurable problem into a subjective one, as long as the *complete requirements* to the code aren't posted. Are new language variants, e.g. Snake 5.x allowed, although Snake 4.x is more common? What about G++-1994? Which version of gawk should compete against which version of GCC (Glorious Chilli Compiler)? Even though we managed to get a rather low number of programming languages, we still need to cover a lot of ground for a *complete answer*.

## Getting a question to scope

The question would have been reasonably scoped, if it instead asked for a *very specific* comparison, or – even better – for a comparison between two programs, e.g.

> ### Why is my Ruby version of the following awk program so slow?
>
> I've written the following script in Ruby to perform an awk-like operation on a large (10M) file:
>
> ```ruby
> File.open("file").readlines.each do |line|
>   line.gsub(/(hit)\s[0-9]*0\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)/) { puts "#{$3} #{$1} #{$2}" }
> end
> ```
>
> On my machine, it takes ~10s. However, the following awk call, which does the same, takes only ~3s.
>
> ```
> awk '/hit [[:digit:]]*0 / { print $4, $1, $3 }' file
> ```
>
> Is there some kind of bottleneck in my Ruby code?

That's a reasonable question (but also a candidate for the code review SE).

## So, what now?

> Is there a recommended place for this?

As we've seen, SO isn't really a place for such questions. Indeed, you could probably write a paper comparing all different implementations. So if you're **really** interested in this problem, what can you do?

Check, whether other pages provide a) the brains and b) the brawn to host such a comparison, e.g. a common hardware that actually provides some means to make those benchmarks comparable.

If there isn't one: congratulations, you just found a new project you can work on.

> Is it not a candidate for community wiki?

No, since a community wiki must still hold the stackoverflow rules.

## TL;DR

If a question can have more than 100 (valid) answers, where each is of equal value as others, it's too broad.

Comment: For the what now, I target using github+travis CI, which will probably allow to address all your points (getting new languages, new versions, comparison on the same hardware) and give a formatted output. Having the output posted into an answer does not sounds technically out of scope (I said technically, I understood there's no place for it here).

Comment: For the result of above comment: http://tensibai.github.io/benchmark-awk-vs/

Answer (score 6):

I've locked this question to give us a day to flesh this out without it continuing to ping-pong between deleted/undeleted and open/closed.

This question has a few issues; none of which are insurmountable, but all of them need to be fixed for this to be an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Let's start with the title:

> What is the performance difference between gawk and …?

The issue here is that Titles are meant to be food for Google. They need good google juice to stand out.  This is sure to attract 'performance' and 'gawk', but how much else?  That's the first clue this question is too broad.

To improve the title, consider adding better keywords and less open ended `...?`.

> The result of this will be an answer that provides a comparison of the performance of different tools performing the basic text processing tasks of regexp matching and field splitting on a simple input file.

This could be the question. Full stop. It don't need anything else:

> What are the benchmarks for each of the following variations of awk (<insert variations here> ) on an <specific reproducible machine here> consider an AWS or Azure VM).

This is a bit broad; but it's better than the current question, and it is specifically bounded to a specific environment and a specific set of variations of awk.

As the questions get longer, the amount of information a user needs to process to know if the question applies to them also increases in proportion. That's bad for us™.  We want users to know (nearly) immediately whether a question is the same on they're facing.  If people wrote good titles, this may not be an issue, [but they don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196744/change-whats-your-programming-question-be-specific-to-what-would-someone-se).

> The way this will work is that over the next couple of days many people will contribute "answers" which are the programs to be tested and then one person (volunteers?) will test all of them on one platform (or a few people will test some subset on their platform so we can compare) and then all of the results will be collected into a single answer.

The OP is just asking for trouble by including this paragraph.  A few reasons why:

1. This way of determining 'answers' is so far outside of Stack Overflow's format that we generally close them as a ['list of X' question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109067/is-a-list-of-x-without-best-still-inappropriate). The OP knew this; (hence the quotes).
2. The OP used the term 'compare'; that's also a red flag for long time SO users. [We generally don't do that well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python). Even when users want us to; they generally find that they don't want to make the changes to make the question and its answers viable. [There are exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), but they are few and far between.
3. The OP says "platform" but doesn't specify the platform.  Make it as specific as possible.  I suggest an AWS t2.micro VM. They're free, and everyone can use one. You can even bump it up to pay by the hour; you're not going to need the VM For very long anyway (an m3.medium isn't that expensive, either; and provides better than the burst CPU provided by the t2.micro).
4. Stick to one language. The OP seems to have PHP, Ruby, Shell, etc; this may be because each can invoke AWK, but that seems like a complicated mess that's only going to be too broad even in the best of circumstances.
5. What's the problem the user is trying to solve?  One of the reasons we don't allow hypothetical questions with no real problem behind them is that the they invite arguments and discussions over minutia. In this case; I could very well see arguments cropping up because this implementation of Ruby's runtime or that implementation don't share the same characteristics; or that someone is using library *x* for JavaScript instead of library *y*.

Possible resolution:

After narrowing it down through the points I included above, flag it for a 'wiki' answer lock; and then people can just update the canonical answer. If the commmunity really wants to contribute (instead of the `volunteers?` question that was posed), then we'll see action, and we'll know we made the right choice by re-opening it.

Otherwise, it's just a lightning rod for the close/reopen groups to pick a question to fight over, and that doesn't do anyone any good.

Comment: Thanks for the lock to avoid the meta effect. For your 4: no it's not invoking awk, it's all about trying to do the same thing as awk and see which one performs better by benchmarking it on the same machine, that's the reason of the multi tagging, getting a code snippet, the most efficient possible, by an expert in this domain to be compared. A try to sum the best from many tags and compare for knowledge. Seems there's no hope for this happening as we can't narrow to your 4 and 5.

Comment: @Tensibai Yea; if the intent is one benchmark of all languages to do the same thing; that's not really good for Stack Overflow.

Comment: All in all the answer is: do the benchmark somewhere, and link to it in comments stating "X or Y will be quicker than Z for this" to avoid talks in comments without facts. (Search comments telling a C program would be faster than that without any evidence, you'll see what I mean)

Comment: Re: "that's not really good for Stack Overflow" This one makes me really sad, we have a place with the better coders in each language, witch can provide the best code to compete and there's no way to ask for it (I hardly see a "What would be the best way in C to mimic this awk code" repeated by each language/tool tag not being closed and question banned)

Comment: @Tensibai I think you mistake SO for the language benchmark. I'm currently on mobile, I'll add a link later if you don't know it yet.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks in advance, I may have badly said it, what I mean is there's on SO perl tag people which will end up with the most efficient code on a particular problem, the same on ruby tag, on C tag, etc. That's quite sad not being able to ask them to contribute this (if they wish to obviously), it's sounds a waste of talents to me. I clearly understood it, and as stated here I think my most active tag should be purged of 80% of its questions.

Comment: @Tensibai If you put it that way: did you check codegolf.stackexchange.com? I'm not a 100% sure, but I think they also provide king off the hill games. (Still mobile)

Comment: @Zeta at first glance it sounds matching, but I suspect the 2 from what is allowed will be a showstopper _An objective primary winning criterion, so that it is possible to indisputably decide which entry should win._ I'm unsure on how to state this part on the current topic. But worth the try rising on codegolf meta for feedback. Thanks for this guidance

Comment: @Tensibai: [Found it](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/). Note that it's quite restricted. You can probably create a fitting king-of-the-hill version, or maybe a nice github page. That's less disputed than a question on SO :).

Comment: @Zeta et al this is an extremely small, simple thing. We constantly get people asking awk performance questions and others saying "if you want it faster, write it in <pick your language du jour>" (see for example the 2nd comment under the Q) and then the jihad begins with zero data to support either side. All I wanted was one Q/A we could point to and say "see for example.." to support or refute general performance claims. It would have been extremely useful and it should not have been a big deal but the reaction from some people has been ridiculous and now it's too late to gather responses.

Comment: @EdMorton That'd be great; a site where you could post benchmarks for different languages doing the same operation.  Unfortunately, as you point out, Stack Overflow isn't that site.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is that site but you need to waste a lot of time searching for the comparisons. Like I say, it's too late now to collect the response that would've made that question useful so don't worry about it, we can all just move on wasting the time of both those asking and those answering the associated questions as usual.

Comment: @EdMorton: You seem quite assured with that statement. If you think that Stack Overflow is really that site (and you seem to have some arguments for your case), feel free to start a new discussion after the current one has cooled down. (Although that's just the optimistic part of me speaking; It's rather unlikely that SO will allow theory finding)

Comment: @Zeta thanks but I'll pass. I've spent WAY too much time on this already, I'll just skip all the future performance questions (or throw in the occasional unsupported "you are right/wrong" comment) so I'm personally not impacted by this as IMHO I've done all I could reasonably be expected to do to try to improve the situation for the community.

Comment: @EdMorton If you're interested on the resulting you may have a quick look [here](http://tensibai.github.io/benchmark-awk-vs/) there's way to improve it, but it's a starting point, we'll see if it has interest to some.

Comment: @Tensibai thanks for doing that! Why are there so many "Results" tables? I notice that for the nawk version you say `nawk  GNU Awk 3.1.8` but nawk and GNU awk are 2 completely different awks.

Comment: @EdMorton Yep, I still did not found the proper package for nawk on ubuntu precise on travis-ci so for now it links to gawk (unsure it's ubuntu or travis behavior). There's a result table for each travis build (triggered by commit on the github repo), keeping the history of builds on different containers sounded interesting to me. I wish to add a database of some sort to order and graph the results (for now it's just a markdown output)

Comment: I really wonder why a moderator undeleted it in June, even though none of these points seem to have been addressed in the 2 months since it was posted. Nor in the 3 since

Comment: @Deduplicator //cc @@timpost can you shed any light on undeletion? I don't agree with it; but you may have received a complaint or something that would say why you undeleted it.

Comment: Seems he didn't hear you.

Answer (score -12):

I voted to reopen the question after it was initially closed (before a moderator closed again) and would vote to reopen it again if I could.

My reasoning is that this was a question by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton). For the people that don't know, Ed is one of the few *real* experts that participate in Stack Overflow. He has left countless correct and well explained answers that have significantly improved that quality of Stack Overflow.

In addition, he has left an even larger amount of helpful comments on other people's answers, often identifying important flaws or bad practices, or just improvements that could be applied. I have personally learned a lot from Ed's helpful comments.

So after 1999 answers, Ed posts his second question and it gets closed twice. I think this decision is not correct, and I hope that the question gets reopened, not only as a way to recognize Ed's contributions, but also because the problem in question is significant and frequently occurring.

Comment: If your reason for declaring a question on-topic is based on who posted it, your reasoning is flawed. So if Jon Skeet posts a question asking for an external library, it should be left open?

Comment: @l4mpi I would not dare close a question of Jon Skeet. Would you?

Comment: Thanks you for phrasing this part. It seems the profile of the user is of no interest and the policy apply blindly, without any guidance on what SO recommend as a stable out site reference.

Comment: Of course I would; based on the same criteria on which I would closevote all other people. Please do not judge a question by its author.

Comment: @l4mpi but Jon Skeet wouldn't ask for a library to use. Libraries would ask Jon Skeet to use them.

Comment: @Tensibai "without any guidance on what SO recommend as a stable out site reference" - why should it  be SOs responsibility to provide guidance on where the people should ask or post the thousands of things that are not on topic for the SE network? There is no guidance where to go for opinionated questions or library requests either, as this is simply _outside of the scope of SO_.

Comment: @Tensibai "asked Nov 18 '09 at 5:44". SO was rather new back then, and its scope wasn't as clearly defined as it is now. Most similar questions from back then are now deleted, some also have a historical lock, and some simply fly under the radar - the question has less than 3k views despite being asked almost 5.5 years ago. And I can assure you that the question would not survive for half an hour if it were to be asked today.

Comment: Who's Jon Skeet ?

Comment: @JID [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=profile)

Comment: @user000001 cool, cheers :)

Comment: @JID he got the most reputation and there are various posts about him on meta. see [Jon Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134) and [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478)